# Sending Email Error -Method Range.getValue

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm using google spreadsheets to send a weekly email to my users with some metric data. I've recently been getting this error:

```
Method Range.getValue is heavily used by the script. File: Code Line: 69
```

Here's line 69 :

```
while (marketReportDataSheet.getRange(AGENT_NAME_ROW,currentDataColumn).getValue() != "") 
{
createMarketReport(marketReportDataSheet, currentDataColumn);
currentDataColumn += 1;
}
```

A copy of the entire script: http://pastebin.com/n70iLPsA

The emails still send out, but the error is also there. I've tried to reduce the amount of times I use the method, but the error still persists. I've looked up this error but can't find any concrete answer even on SO. Any solutions or  point in the right direction would be more than greatly appreciated.

Comment: How many times does the `while` loop iterate?  If the loop only runs once, change it to an `if` condition.  `if (marketReportDataSheet.getRange(AGENT_NAME_ROW,currentDataColumn).getValue() != "")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Most of the function calls that you make to the APIs listed in GAS
>   will require more time than regular JavaScript. In your case, reduce
>   the number of calls to Range and Sheet classes

Here's sample code you may use:

```
  var lastCol = marketReportDataSheet.getDataRange().getLastColumn();

  var data = sheet.getRange(AGENT_NAME_ROW,currentDataColumn,1,lastCol).getValues()[0];

      for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

        if (data[i] != "" && data[i] != undefined) {
          createMarketReport(marketReportDataSheet, i+1);
        }

      }
```

Comment: I've inputted the above sample, however I now get an error "ReferenceError: "sheet" is not defined."

Comment: You should replace sheet to your variable name: marketReportDataSheet

Comment: Thanks again Max, I appreciate your help. 

I did that and I now have an error where the email is launched on line 120: 

    "Invalid email: Seller's (line 120, file "Code")"

Comment: I quess, this error doesn't relate to original problem. `Invalid email: Seller's` means you entered 'Seller's' instead of email to respective variable.